# How can I prompt user to accept push notifications outside of AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app loads into a view controller that tells the user why they should accept push notifications. It isn't until AFTER they press the Continue button on this view controller that I want them to be prompted with accepting the push notifications. This means that I would need to include the code somewhere in my initial view controller, let us call it **BeforePromptController**. I am using Firebase in case it matters.

Here is my working code in AppDelegate (however I want to change it so the prompt happens after user presses Continue button in BeforePromptController). I tried to only include the important parts of AppDelegate here..

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }        

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active {

            var pushNotificationMessage = ""
            if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
                        pushNotificationMessage = message as String
                    }
                } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
                    pushNotificationMessage = alert as String
                }
            }

            let notificationAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: pushNotificationMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {
                (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            })
            defaultAction.setValue(Constants.activePushNotificationOKColor, forKey: "titleTextColor")

            notificationAlert.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(notificationAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just move the code after `FIRApp.configure()` where you need to ask the authorization; you can get a reference of application with `UIApplication.shared`

Answer (score 0):

the prompt about the push notifications will appear once you call `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()`, so, calling to this function you will show the prompt when you want.

To access to your UIApplication you can use `UIApplication.shared` in Swift3 or `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` in Swift2